# AbInitio - Include Additional Headers in Call SOAP HTTP Service UTF8

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, ab-initio

I am trying to use the **Call SOAP HTTP Service UTF8** component to call the webservice in AbInitio graph.

But an additional header, X-Authorization is mandatory and needs to be passed.

From the WSDL, I have imported, I can see the SOAP env and body schema but cannot find a provision for passing the X-Authorization parameter.

Can someone please advise on how this can be achieved?

Please let me know if you need further info

Comment: If you used a tutorial to do this, you could post the relevant parts you did in here too.

Comment: @JChomel - I haven't used any tutorial. The abinitio component ,** Call SOAP HTTP Service UTF8** , has the parameters for WSDL, SOAP Action etc whic I was able to pass.

Comment: Are you calling it graphically?

Answer (score 0):

On the graphic interface of the soap web service I know (obsolete [oc4j](/questions/tagged/oc4j)), there is an auth. part to fulfill:

[image: Ocaj SOAP]

If using `wget`, then add `--user` ... `--ask-password` ....

```
wget --user <my user> --ask-password  <my url>...
```

Comment: @JChomel - Thanks for that. But, my question is specifically when using the Abinitio graph component. Also,if I am right, the above screenshot shows the variable where I could enter the HTTP user name and password. Isnt the X-Authorization a completely different/additional to the generally used HHTP username and password ?

Comment: Not necessarily. It could just be a missing user/password somewhere. You use "Abinitio graph component", but what does that mean? Could you update your question either to show the code where you use it, or a screenshot of the GUI if any?